# Force an enter event in an input with jQuery

Tags: jquery, keypress

I have an input which changes value when a click a button. What I want to do is to force an enter keypress event with jQuery. without pressing the button. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

jQuerys `.trigger()` should do the trick:

```
$('input').trigger({
    type: 'keypress',
    which: 13
});
```

Ref.: [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: cheers jAndy, this helped me chain a button to hit enter on an input box

Answer (score 1):

`$(element).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
 do_something();
});`

Comment: I think it doesn't work as well. I don't want to capture the keypress and do something. I want to force an enter keypress with code.

Comment: Ok. Is running $(element).keydown() on your element enought? You won't get the event id this way but a general keydown(). I don't think it's possible to set event id. May .submit() be close enough to simulate a event with id 13 maybe?

Answer (score -1):

I needed to use this on a search box to clear it's content...but instead of using 'keypress' or 'keydown', I needed to use 'keyup' so that the search function would fire also.  This way I could clear the limiting search results.